# How to make this AMP

Tags: amp-html

I would like to convert this in AMP friendly version.

`<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=1de6a627-71a8-4067-8f65-66f92af80306&storeId=simple"></script>`

Comment: Try putting that component in an `<amp-iframe>`

Comment: I have did but not showing anything.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of what you did? And is this just a JS widget?

Comment: `<amp-iframe width=300 height=300
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US&adInstanceId=1de6a627-71a8-4067-8f65-66f92af80306&storeId=simple">
</amp-iframe>`

Comment: First off, the URL in `src` must be `https`. If that doesn't work, try creating another page using normal HTML, ie. `foo.bar/widget.html`, and use that in the `amp-iframe`, ie. `<amp-iframe ... src="https://foo.bar/widget.html" >`. Not exactly sure if this will work but it doesn't hurt to test it out.

Comment: Additional info about amp-iframe is in the [example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/), you can use this to contents not yet supported by AMP. First thing is to import the amp-iframe component in the header. There are also other sample like Google Maps, Vimeo and Giphy code implementation. Hope this helps.